# Python: Replace a string in JSON file

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am new to python.my requirement is i want to replace a string in a big json file. My code only replace the string 1 time. Not sure why its not updating for the second time.

```
#!/bin/bash
import json


with open("blueprint_image1.txt", "r") as f1:
 content = json.load(f1)
 content1 = content["blueprints"][0]["imagename"]
 content2 = content["blueprints"][1]["imagename"]
 content3 = content["blueprints"][2]["imagename"]

images = ['redhat_q1', 'redhat_q2', 'redhat_q3']

change_content = content

for i in images:
 change_content["blueprints"][0]["imagename"] = content["blueprints"][0]["imagename"].replace(content1, i)
 print change_content["blueprints"][0]["imagename"]
 change_content["blueprints"][1]["imagename"] = content["blueprints"][0]["imagename"].replace(content2, i)
 print change_content["blueprints"][1]["imagename"]
```

Below is the file from which i am taking the values.

```
{
        "blueprints": [{
                "blueprintname": "ABC",
                "imagename": "REDHAT_7_2020Q1"
        }, {
                "blueprintname": "XXXX",
                "imagename": "REDHAT_7_2020Q2"
        }, {
                "blueprintname": "YYY",
                "imagename": "REDHAT_7_2020Q3"
        }]
}
```

Here i want to replace the imagenames with the content in images list. it works fine for the first time.. wont change the value in the 2nd and 3rd loop.. am i missing something ? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the wrong index to `content` in this line: `change_content["blueprints"][1]["imagename"] = content["blueprints"][0]["imagename"].replace(content2, i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing error of your mistake. You constantly change the same value.
Secondly the replace() function is not change orginal value.

```
import json


with open("blueprint_image1.txt", "r") as f1:
    content = json.load(f1)

images = ['redhat_q1', 'redhat_q2', 'redhat_q3']

change_content = content

for i in range(len(images)):
    change_content["blueprints"][i]["imagename"] = images[i]
    print(change_content["blueprints"][i]["imagename"])
```

this will work for you.

Defining in a loop is always good. No need to write extra code

Comment: Thank you so much @salih.. It works fine now.. Appreciate it